# How to extract the aggregated gradient from tensorflow_federated?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I have a tensorflow model like this

```
def input_spec():
return(
      tf.TensorSpec([None, 122], tf.float64),
      tf.TensorSpec([None, 5],tf.uint8))

def model_fn():
    model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,input_shape=(122,)),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.15),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.15),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.15),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(5,activation='softmax')])
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
           model,
           input_spec=input_spec(),
           loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
           metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
```

I set the iterative_process in the following

```
iterative_process=tff.learning.algorithms.build_weighted_fed_avg(
                  model_fn,
                  client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
```

I have learnt that we can obtain the aggregated weight by `model_weights=iterative_process.get_model_weights(state)`, but I still need to know how to obtain the aggregated gradients.

Answer (score 1):

While running the training procedure, the aggregated (pseudo) gradients can in some cases be computed by subtracting the state at the beginning of the round from that at the end. In the code snippet above, this will not quite literally be true since the server optimizer is Adam (which performs some rescaling of the pseudo-gradients, as well as the addition of a momentum accumulator, if I recall correctly).

If you are simply using gradient-descent with a learning rate of 1 on the server (traditionally the default setting for `FedAvg`), code like the following should give you this aggregated pseudogradient:

```
pseudo_grad = tf.nest.map_structure(
        lambda x, y: x - y, previous_state.global_model_weights.trainable,
        state.global_model_weights.trainable)
```

Some helpful measurements for debugging can alternatively be accessed by wrapping the aggregator parameter to your `build_weighted_fed_avg` call in an [aggregator that adds these debug measurements](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/add_debug_measurements), if this is the underlying goal here. You would additionally be  able to read these values directly if you implemented a [`tff.templates.AggregationProcess`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/templates/AggregationProcess) which output the averaged pseudogradient in the [`measurements`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/templates/MeasuredProcessOutput) field of its result; these should be passed through directly by the rest of the FedAvg implementation.

Comment: According to your comment, I want to know how to find previous_state and state

Comment: According to your comment, I have got the 'pseudo_grad', but I am not sure about how to obtain the grad directly by measurement in 'tff.templates.AggregationProcess'

Comment: By the way, do you know how to extract the gradient from tensorflow?